# Java изменить числа в строке

Tags: java, android, строки, числа

Можно ли программно изменить все числа в строке одинаковым образом, если заведомо неизвестно неизвестно, что за строка? 
К примеру, у меня есть две строки:

```
 <string name="str1">текст 2 текст 4 текст 8 текст 16</string>
<string name="str2">другой текст 1 другой текст 3 другой текст 9 другой текст 27</string>
```

А TextView только один, и заполняется он одной из строк, то есть:

```
if(блаблабла){textView.setText(str1);} else if(блаблаблабла){textView.setText(str2);}
```

Хочу, чтобы на выходе содержимое textView было таким:

```
текст 4 текст 8 текст 16 текст 32 //для str1
другой текст 2 другой текст 6 другой текст 18 другой текст 54 //для str2
```

Для сего я изобрёл следующую адскую конструкцию:

```
 char[] num = textView.getText().toString().toCharArray(); //берем текст и сразу зашвыриваем в массив
int[] xar=new int[2]; int x;StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder(); //это пригодится по ходу дела
for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++){ //пробегаемся по каждому элементу массива 
for(int i1=0;i1<10;i1++){ 
if(num[i]==i1){ //смотрим число ли этот элемент
xar[0]=i1; for( i1=0;i1<10;i1++){ // если число, то записываем его в другой массив, и пробегаемся по следующему элементу первого массива, потому что число может быть двузначным
if(num[i+1]==i1){
xar[1]=i1;sb.append(num);sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);}// если и он число, тогда тоже записываем его в другой массив, а из первого массива удаляем
else {sb.append(xar);sb.deleteCharAt(1);}}// если нету двух чисел подряд, то удаляем ненужный элемент из второго массива, ибо мы его ничем не заполнили
for (int q : xar) {sb.append(q);}x = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString())*2; //переводим получившийся массив в число и умножаем на два, как нам и нужно
char xint = Integer.toString(x).charAt(0);num[i]=xint; //в исходном массиве заменяем элемент, который является числом, нашим получившимся числом
String put2 = new String(num);brez1.setText(put2); }}}
```

На выходе я получаю пустоту. Чего-чего, а этого я не ожидал. Совсем не понимаю, в чём может быть дело :/ Может есть какие-нибудь готовые шаблоны для решения моей задачи?

Comment: А что вы конкретно хотите сделать? Заменить числа в строке или же увеличить каждое число в строке в два раза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код можно упростить, если вынести проверку, является ли символ числом, в отдельную функцию (или взять стандартную), собирать новую строку через `StringBuilder` (все равно в старый массив она не влезет), и т.п. Итоговый результат получился какой-то такой:

```
private static String usingLoop( String str ) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for ( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ) {
        // isDigit так же возвращает true для всяких индийских цифр,
        //   можно написать '0' <= c && c <= '9'
        if ( Character.isDigit( chars[i] ) ) { 
            int holder = Character.digit( chars[i], 10 );
            i++;
            while( i < chars.length && Character.isDigit( chars[i] ) ) {
                holder = holder * 10 + Character.digit( chars[i], 10 );
                i++;
            }
            int multipliedInt = holder * 2;
            result.append( multipliedInt );

            if ( i >= chars.length ) {
                return result.toString();
            }
        }
        result.append( chars[i] );
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Можно сделать через регулярки:

```
private static String usingPatternMatcher( String str ) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\\d+" );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( str );
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int prev = 0;
    while ( matcher.find() ) {
        result.append( str.substring( prev, matcher.start() ) );

        int multipliedInt = Integer.parseInt( matcher.group() ) * 2;
        result.append( multipliedInt );

        prev = matcher.end();
    }
    result.append( str.substring( prev ) );

    return result.toString();
}
```

в такой вариант, в качестве бонуса, несложно добавить работу с вещественными числами.

Comment: То, что надо, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5):

Используйте replaceAll, пометьте все цифры символом, замените эти символы на любые другие цифры.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "текст 2текст4 текст8 текст16";
    String str2 = "";
    str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+", "__");

    String[] textList = str.trim().split("__");

    for (int i =0; i < textList.length; i++){
        str2 += " " + textList[i] + " " + i;
    }
    System.out.println(str2);
}
```

Результат: `текст  0 текст 1  текст 2  текст 3`

Comment: не понимаю, где в вашем коде заменять числа

Comment: @i am so lame, в методе replaceAll() как раз происходит замена символов. Первый параметр этого метода - это регулярное выражение, которое определяет какие именно символы нужно заменять. Второй параметр - это то чем вы хотите заменять.

Comment: к сожалению, я не могу знать заранее, какие числа мне нужны на выходе, это зависит от того, что за строка содержится в textView.